# Use QuickCheck by generating primes

Tags: haskell, properties, rsa, generator, quickcheck

**Background**

For fun, I'm trying to write a property for quick-check that can test the basic idea behind [cryptography with RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA).

- Choose two distinct primes, `p` and `q`.
- Let `N = p*q`
- `e` is some number [relatively prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_prime) to `(p-1)(q-1)` (in practice, e is usually 3 for fast encoding)
- `d` is the [modular inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_inverse) of `e` modulo `(p-1)(q-1)`

For all `x` such that `1 < x < N`, it is always true that `(x^e)^d = x modulo N`

In other words, `x` is the "message", raising it to the `e`th power mod `N` is the act of "encoding" the message, and raising the encoded message to the `d`th power mod `N` is the act of "decoding" it.

(The property is also trivially true for `x = 1`, a case which is its own encryption)

**Code**

Here are the methods I have coded up so far:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

-- modular exponentiation
modExp :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> a
modExp y z n = modExp' (y `mod` n) z `mod` n
    where modExp' y z | z == 0 = 1
                      | even z =  modExp (y*y) (z `div` 2) n
                      | odd z  = (modExp (y*y) (z `div` 2) n) * y

-- relatively prime
rPrime :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
rPrime a b = gcd a b == 1

-- multiplicative inverse (modular)
mInverse :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
mInverse 1 _ = 1
mInverse x y = (n * y + 1) `div` x
    where n = x - mInverse (y `mod` x) x

-- just a quick way to test for primality
n `divides` x = x `mod` n == 0
primes = 2:filter isPrime [3..]
isPrime x = null . filter (`divides` x) $ takeWhile (\y -> y*y <= x) primes

-- the property
prop_rsa (p,q,x) = isPrime p  &&
                   isPrime q  &&
                   p /= q     &&
                   x > 1      &&
                   x < n      &&
                   rPrime e t ==>
                   x == (x `powModN` e) `powModN` d
    where e = 3
          n = p*q
          t = (p-1)*(q-1)
          d = mInverse e t
          a `powModN` b = modExp a b n
```

(Thanks, google and random blog, for the [implementation of modular multiplicative inverse](http://cdsmith.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/calculating-multiplicative-inverses-in-modular-arithmetic/))

**Question**

The problem should be obvious: there are way too many conditions on the property to make it at all usable. Trying to invoke `quickCheck prop_rsa` in ghci made my terminal hang.

So I've poked around the [QuickCheck manual](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Erjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html) a bit, and it says:

> Properties may take the form
>
> `forAll <generator> $ \<pattern> -> <property>`

How do I make a `<generator>` for prime numbers? Or with the other constraints, so that `quickCheck` doesn't have to sift through a bunch of failed conditions?

Any other general advice (especially regarding QuickCheck) is welcome.

Comment: Fun fact: QuickCheck helped me see that `q` and `p` *must* be distinct. Before I had that requirement, it was able to find examples that failed the prop when `q == p`

Comment: Props man, this is a beautifully asked question. Few people put this much effort into communicating what they want to know. Upvote.

Comment: You could use the Rabin-Miller probabilistic test; http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rabin-MillerStrongPseudoprimeTest.html

Comment: Just found an implementation of the Rabin-Miller test here: http://bonsaicode.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/programming-praxis-primality-checking/

Comment: @Paul very nice! I've been working on tweaking the test so that it only uses small primes, mainly because testing larger numbers for primality was getting cumbersome. I'll take a look at working that into my code instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so here's what I did.

Top of file

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Test.QuickCheck
import Control.Applicative
```

All code as given in the question, except for prop_rsa. That was (obviously) heavily modified:

```
prop_rsa = forAll primePair $ \(p,q) ->
           let n = p*q
           in forAll (genUnder n) $ \x  ->
              let e = 3
                  t = (p-1)*(q-1)
                  d = mInverse e t
                  a `powModN` b = modExp a b n
              in p /= q &&
                 rPrime e t ==>
                 x == (x `powModN` e) `powModN` d
```

The type for `primePair` is `Gen (Int, Int)`, and the type for `genUnder` is `Int -> Gen Int`. I'm not exactly sure what the magic is behind `forAll` but I'm pretty sure this is correct. I've done some ad-hoc adjustments to 1) make sure it fails if I mess up the conditions and 2) make sure the nested `forAll` is varying the value of `x` across test cases.

So here's how to write those generators. Once I realized that `<generator>` in the documentation just meant something of type `Gen a`, it was cake.

```
genNonzero = (\x -> if x == 0 then 1 else x) `fmap` arbitrary
genUnder :: Int -> Gen Int
genUnder n = ((`mod` n) . abs) `fmap` genNonzero

genSmallPrime = ((\x -> (primes !! (x `mod` 2500))) . abs) `fmap` arbitrary

primePair :: Gen (Int, Int)
primePair = (,) <$> genSmallPrime <*> genSmallPrime
```

`primePair` took some trial and error for me to get right; I knew that some combinators like that *should* work, but I'm still not as familiar with `fmap`, `<$>` and `<*>` as I'd like to be. I restricted the computation to only select from among the first 2500 primes; otherwise it apparently wanted to pick some really big ones that took forever to generate.

**Random thing to note**

Thanks to laziness, `d = mInverse e t` isn't computed unless the conditions are met. Which is good, because it's undefined when the condition `rPrime e t` is false. In English, an integer `a` only has a multiplicative inverse (mod b) when `a` and `b` are relatively prime.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to make a QuickCheck-compatible prime-number generator (stealing a Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation from http://en.literateprograms.org/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes_(Haskell)):

```
import Test.QuickCheck

newtype Prime = Prime Int deriving Show

primes = sieve [2..]
    where
      sieve (p:xs) = Prime p : sieve [x | x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]

instance Arbitrary Prime where
    arbitrary = do i <- arbitrary
                   return $ primes!!(abs i)
```

It can be used in QuickCheck like so:

```
prop_primes_dont_divide (Prime x) (Prime y) = x == y || x `mod` y > 0
```

For your use, you'd replace `p` and `q` with `(Prime p)` and `(Prime q)` in your property.

Comment: You might want to use library code for the primes, it should be faster by a decent amount: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes

Comment: @barsoap probably better than what I or jacobm wrote, but the docs for `isPrime` currently say, "It is impractical for numbers with a very large smallest prime factor." Wikipedia has loads of interesting information on faster [primality tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) that I might try out.

Comment: this is a good answer; I tried it out and it was pretty good. But not quite what I was asking for. I'm particularly interested in using `forAll` here. Inspired by your answer I've actually come up with some stuff, but I want to wait and see if anyone else has something insightful to say before I post it.